# Smooth drag and drop transition

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, pascal

I'm creating a program for kids and one of the mini-games is dragging a mouse into a hole. The dragging has no animation in between unless I put a function on the *OnDragOver* event of the underlying picture. This, however, does not work properly, because the background gets obscured by the dragged picture.
Ideally the picture'd snap its center to the cursor and move around with the mouse.

Any advice?

Here's a GIF of how it looks like now:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately drag and drop feature that Delphi provides is not useful for what you are trying to achieve.

So you will have to make your own dragging system for this.

Here is a basic code example that will show you how to achieve this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Panel1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Panel1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Panel1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  //Variable to tell whether dragging is in progress
  IsDragging: Boolean;
  //Variable for storing the cursor position above component when dragging has started
  //We use this to keep the component in same relative position to mouse cursors
  //during the dragging
  GrabPos: TPoint;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  //Store the information where mouse cursor was in relation to the component when
  //dragging has started
  GrabPos.X := X;
  GrabPos.Y := Y;
  //Set IsDragging to true to tell the program that dragging process is in progress
  IsDragging := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  //Check to see if dragging process is in progress
  if IsDragging then
  begin
    //Set new component position relative to mouse cursor position
    //NOTE
    // - We don't use X and Y mouse position that is returned by the event. Instead
    //   we are using global mouse cursor position available through Mouse.CursorPos.
    //   This is necessary because X and Y parameters that are returned by the event
    //   are relative to the current component position which is constantly changing
    //   during the dragging process
    // - Since Mouse.CursorPos is using global (screen) coordinates wee need to change
    //   then into relative coordinates of our application.
    //   Because Let and Top properties of any component are relative to the parent
    //   component on which your component resides you need to make sure that you always
    //   use parent components ScreenToClient method.
    //   So if you would have your component on another panel for instance you would
    //   have to call
    //   TPanel(sender).Left := AnotherPanel.ScreenToClient(MouseCursorPos).X - GrabPos.X;
    // - Sender is reference to the component that fired the mentioned event.
    //   You can use this in order to write one event method that can work with multiple
    //   components.
    TPanel(sender).Left := ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos).X - GrabPos.X;
    TPanel(sender).Top := ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos).Y - GrabPos.Y;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  //Set IsDragging to false to tell the program that dragging process is no longer in progress
  IsDragging := False;
end;

end.
```

In my example I'm using global variables but I would recommend that you instead subclass the components that you use for your images and build this into them.

Main advantage of this would be ability to be dragging multiple components simultaneously (can be useful on multi-touch systems) which is not possible with my example.

My example works perfectly on VCL applications but I think it should also work with FireMonkey applications (FMX) but I haven't tested it out.

Comment: I feel dumb for not understanding an example code, but the "Panel" is supposed to be the TImage moved around or the TImage in the background?

Comment: @Tallmios Yes! You can replace Panel with TImage component or any other VCL component you like.